# How to detach ebpf cgroup programs without using bpftool?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, cgroups

I am using Cilium ebpf to attach programs to cgroups. However, in my code I didn’t detach the program correctly and now I have some cgroup programs running in the background and I am trying to look for other ways to close them.

I tried to delete everything with `bpftool cgroup detach CGROUP ATTACH_TYPE PROG`, and when I run bpftool cgroup tree at first, I get nothing in the tree. I then ran `bpftool prog show`but still got cgroup programs running like the following:

```
1096: cgroup_device  tag 47dd357395126b0c  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 504B  jited 309B  memlock 4096B
1097: cgroup_skb  tag 6deef7357e7b4530  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 64B  jited 54B  memlock 4096B
1098: cgroup_skb  tag 6deef7357e7b4530  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 64B  jited 54B  memlock 4096B
1099: cgroup_device  tag b73cbcf8b8c71a5b  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 496B  jited 307B  memlock 4096B
1100: cgroup_skb  tag 6deef7357e7b4530  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 64B  jited 54B  memlock 4096B
1101: cgroup_skb  tag 6deef7357e7b4530  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 64B  jited 54B  memlock 4096B
1102: cgroup_device  tag ce28cc67158d681f  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 744B  jited 447B  memlock 4096B
1103: cgroup_skb  tag 6deef7357e7b4530  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 64B  jited 54B  memlock 4096B
1104: cgroup_skb  tag 6deef7357e7b4530  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:36:22-0500  uid 0
        xlated 64B  jited 54B  memlock 4096B
1105: cgroup_device  tag 26dcd5a87c1d07a2  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:40:36-0500  uid 0
        xlated 440B  jited 268B  memlock 4096B
1106: cgroup_device  tag ab4bc4523b7fe6b4
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:40:36-0500  uid 0
        xlated 552B  jited 353B  memlock 4096B
1107: cgroup_device  tag 26dcd5a87c1d07a2  gpl
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:40:36-0500  uid 0
        xlated 440B  jited 268B  memlock 4096B
1108: cgroup_device  tag ab4bc4523b7fe6b4
        loaded_at 2023-02-23T13:40:36-0500  uid 0
        xlated 552B  jited 353B  memlock 4096B
```

What's more, whenever I restart my virtual machine and type `bpftool cgroup tree`, my previously empty tree has content again. Here is what's shown when `bpftool cgroup tree` is called:

```
CgroupPath
ID       AttachType      AttachFlags     Name           
/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/systemd-udevd.service
    1844     ingress                                        
    1843     egress                                         
    1842     device          multi                          
/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/docker-c515f626ae992e61d4894704823a9fbc41ce42fbc7a8e4b26cc7ca07ba5ef1cb.scope
    1865     device          multi                          
/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/systemd-journald.service
    1840     ingress                                        
    1839     egress                                         
    1838     device          multi                          
/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/docker-67d06fd3514a55c180718472791e45aae102830f6d35e1c6acf073598115a5ee.scope
    1869     device          multi                          
/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/systemd-logind.service
    1848     ingress                                        
    1847     egress                                         
    1846     device          multi
```

I tried to delete everything with `bpftool cgroup detach CGROUP ATTACH_TYPE PROG` again, but these programs don't seem to go away. To prevent further leakage I froze the maps and got rid of them. If I try to delete these programs using `bpftool prog detach PROG ATTACH_TYPE [MAP]`, I get either failure to detach from map or several programs have the same handle.

For the cgroups that belong to docker containers, I can fix the issue by simply removing the docker containers. For the other cgroups, I am unsure whether there are other ways to detach these programs without needing to use bpftool.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BPF programs are loaded in the kernel and attached to hook points. **If you detach them, they remain loaded in the kernel** and you will therefore see them in `bpftool prog show`. Those shouldn't matter however because they are not attached anywhere; at most, they consume a bit of memory in the kernel.

Note that systemd installs some BPF cgroup programs. That's probably why you see some even after a reboot.